# Laravel 5 - eloquent model - 3 tables in series

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**Scenario** - I have 3 tables > Country, State, City. City have stateid column, State have countryid column, country have no reference.

City Model methods

```
public function state(){ 
    return $this->belongsTo('App\State', 'stateid');
}
```

State Model methods

```
public function country(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Country', 'countryid');
}
public function cities(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\City', 'stateid');
}
```

Country Model methods

```
public function states()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\State', 'countryid');
}
```

**Problem** - I want to get the list of cities in a country. How can I create a method in Country Model like this? -

```
public function cities(){
    return $this->states()->cities(); //Calling hasMany on builder is not possible.
}
```

Similarly, a method to country name from city model.

Comment: What you are looking for is, `hasManyThrough()`. See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: @Mysteryos - Thanks, that worked.

Comment: @Mysteryos - is there a way to get country from city?

Comment: `$city->state->country`, you will have to eager load when iterating.

Comment: @user2094178 - sorry, couldn't get you..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve a Collection with all cities in a Country, use the hasManyThrough method:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function states()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(State::class);
    }

    public function cities()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(City::class, State::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if a country only has cities and not states? How will this implementation react?

Answer (score 0):

Country Model:

```
<?php

    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Country_master extends Model
    {    

        public function city_state_data()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\State_master','city_masters');
        }  
    }
```

Call Model:

```
<?php
    $data=Country_master::find(1)->city_state_data()->select('city_name','state_name')->get();
```